# Open full URL in browser from postman

Tags: postman

I am using postman and my saved endpoint have a bunch of variable in it, how do I open the full generated URL with variable filled in from a browser?

```
{{protocol}}://api.{{URL}}/oauth2/authorize?state=z3qAr0h5Ud&client_id={{oauth2_app_id}}&response_type=code
```

[image]

I could fill in each parameter manually in the browser window but that's a hassle and I would prefer if I can get the fully filled URL, is this possible in postman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the Code view on the top-right, it should have the url filled with your variables (doesn't matter which language). I set my `oauth2_app_id` to `test1` and you can see it in the url where it is highlighted (I did not set the other variables, only the oauth).

**Open Code view**

[image]

**See the url**

[image]